# Converting to Structure Query language (SQL) Array?

Tags: sql, sas

```
/*Convert Below data step into SQL code*/   
 data Dataset1;
 set Initial_dataset;
        array Events{7} Event1-Event7;
        do i=1 to 7;
            if Events{i} ^= '' then do; 
                Event_Num=cats("Event",i);
                Event_CD=Events{i};
                output;
            end;
        end;
        drop i Event1-Event7;
    run;
```

Input:

```
Column_1 | Event1 | Event2 | Event3 | Event4 | Event5 | Event6 | Event7
123456   |  123   |        |        |        |        |        |       
234567   |  123   |  234   |        |        |        |        |
345678   |        |        |  123   |        |        |        |                             
...
```

Output:

```
Column_1 | Event_Num | Event_cd | 
123456   | Event1    | 123      |
234567   | Event1    | 123      |
234567   | Event2    | 234      |
345678   | Event1    | 123      |
...
```

Comment: Hi - on this site people will help you when you are struggling to resolve an issue but they aren't just going to do your homework for you. If you show what you have done so far and what, in particular, you need help with then you are more likely to get a response.

Comment: You will need to code a UNION of 7 sub-selects (`select 1 as event_num, event1 from mytable where event1 is not missing`), for each event and order that by the key and event_num .